# Can't get Node js response object in a Javascript using ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

This is my response code in node js.

```
app.get('/receive', async function (req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index', {
        items: returndata.data
    });
});
```

I want to load the data into a Jquery Data Table. So I am using the following script in the script.js.

```
var records = <% - JSON.stringify(items)  %>
console.log(records);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        data: records
    });
});
```

When I run this code, browser throws,`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in `script.js:1`. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Your script isn't processed by ejs, just the view you pass (`pages/index`). You need to move the `var records` line into an inline `<script>` in your view. Another way is to set up an express route that calls `res.send(returndata.data);` and request it from your script via ajax.

Comment: `Your script isn't processed by ejs, just the view you pass ` What does it mean?

Comment: `app.use(express.static('public'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`
This lines not enough?

Comment: Let's put it this way: I assume you have a file like `views/pages/index.ejs`? That file is opened by the view engine (ejs) and processed, becoming a standard HTML document in the process. It is sent to the browser and the browser will now request `script.js` from the server. Since that is a static file, it is sent as-is. So again, if you want to pass data from the server to the client, create an appropriate endpoint or dump it as inline script into a view. `*.js` files aren't processed by the view engine.

Comment: I directly given this in index.js also. 
    `<script type="text/javascript">
        var records = <%= JSON.stringify(items) %>
</script>`
Still not working.

Comment: What exactly does "Still not working" mean? What do you see when you look at the source code (press Ctrl+U)?